# Qt building sequence (rcc -> uic -> moc -> preprocessor -> normal compiler)?

Tags: c++, qt, build-process

Please I wanna know the order in which these building tools are called in QT prjects :
The UIC - The MOC - The RCC - The preprocessor - The normal c++ compiler (e.g Gcc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First step :

UIC process the *.ui files and produce *.h outputs
MOC process the *.h files (those with Q_OBJECT macro) and produce moc_*.cpp files
RCC process the *.rc files and produce *.cpp files

Second step :

All your writed *.h/*.cpp files and all the generated *.h/*.cpp files are processed as "normal" source code by your "normal" compiler.

For a complete answer, you should know that qMake create dependencies between these files.
For example if "foo.h" file contain the "Q_OBJECT" macro, MOC will produce "moc_foo.cpp" file.
But qMake will add a dependency : "moc_foo.cpp" will be marked as dependent on "foo.h".
So, if you modify "foo.h" file, your compiler knows that MOC should be re-run on this file to produce the new version of "moc_foo.cpp"

Comment: This depends of the build system used. It is marked in the make files for GCC or using build rules in Visual Studio projects. I don't know for MacOS since I don't use it. Look at your solution/project files (make, nmake, vcproj...) it is writed in it.